# Simulation from generalized linear model with specific signal to noise ratio

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, simulation, noise

I am trying to simulate from a generalized linear model (GLM) in a specific signal to noise ratio (SNR) setting, but run in to problems if I try to define a reasonable SNR for non-Gaussian data.

In Elements of Statistical Learning, Section 16.2.2, Figure 16.2 (Haste, Tibshirani, and Friedman, 2009, 12th printing) the noise-to-signal ratio (NSR) in a GLM with linear predictor $\eta(X)=X^T\beta$ is defined as:
$$
NSR = \frac{\text{Var}(Y|\eta(X))}{\text{Var}(\eta(X))}.
$$
That leads to a SNR of:
$$
SNR = \frac{\text{Var}(\eta(X))}{\text{Var}(Y|\eta(X))}.
$$
In Gaussian models, i.e., $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(X^T\beta,\sigma^2)$, this results in a reasonable and fairly standard SNR of
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{Var}(X^T\beta)}{\sigma^2}.
\end{equation}
However, for general GLMs this means that the variance of the signal in the numerator is on the linear predictor scale, while the variance of the noise in the denominator is on the response variable scale. My intuition says that both the numerator as well as the denominator should be on the response variable scale, i.e.:
$$
SNR = \frac{\text{Var}[\text{E}(Y|\eta(X))]}{\text{Var}(Y|\eta(X))}=
\frac{\text{Var}[g^{-1}(\eta(X))]}{\text{Var}(Y|\eta(X))},
$$
with $g$ the chosen link function. This SNR still leads to the same Gaussian SNR above, but makes more sense to me in the non-Gaussian setting.

I'm fairly certain people have dealt with this before, I just couldn't really find anything on it. So my question is, have you ever dealt with such a setting, and if so, what SNR definition did you use in the non-Gaussian GLM case.

Note, I am not looking to estimate a SNR; I want to simulate from a GLM in specified SNR setting.